# How to pass parameter to routes?

Tags: node.js, routes, parameter-passing

I am using Nodejs .

Server.js

```
app.get('/dashboard/:id', routes.dashboard);
```

Routes / index.js

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res){


}
```

I want to be able to pass the 'id' variable from app.js to the dashboard function . How do I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming ExpressJS, you shouldn't need to pass it.

For each parameter placeholder (like `:id`), [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) should have a matching property holding the value:

```
exports.dashboard = function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
};
```

Though, this assumes the requested URL matches the route by verb and pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Just ensure that your `GET` call from the client is something like this: `/dashboard/12345`.
`12345` is the id you want to pass to `dashboard`.

So, you can access it like this in server:

```
exports.dashboard = function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('ID in dashboard: %s', id);
}
```