# NodeJS : Access static ressources from third level routes in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm having trouble accessing my /public folder ressources from a /admin/item/[id] route.

Here is my file structure :

- app.js
- admin

  - index.js
- public

  - img
  - js
  - css
- views

**/app.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //Access OK
    res.render('index');
});
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
```

**/admin/index.js**

```
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
router.get('/upload/', (req, res) => {
        //Access OK
    res.render('admin/upload');
});
router.get('/album/:albumid', (req, res) => {
    //No access
    res.render('admin/album');
}):
```

Is there a way to set the routes individually ? Is this a good practice ?
Or is there a way to set a general path using express.static ?

Thank you all

Comment: `/admin/item/[id]` ?? Can you clarify that?I do not see your endpoint

Comment: I'm passing the id of the album that I want to edit. For example : /album/id_of_the_album. Just like it is done in this post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398766/how-to-pass-parameter-to-routes

Comment: And when you say, "access to the public folder" you mean from the UI? I see you are rendering a view

Comment: When trying to access my js or CSS files from the browser, I've got à 404. The path looks like this : localhost:3000/admin/album/css/style.css instead of going into the public folder that is in the root of my project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a relative path for static assets like

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

Then in your html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

O however you have you static folder structure.

Comment: And this relative path will be the same for all routes even second of third level ?

Comment: Notice the slash `href="/static/` that will be relative to your domain, wherever the endpoint you are.

Comment: Thank you very much